# logging.getLogger(__name__) default inheritance not working

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a project with the following hierarchy:

```
ModuleA:
- __main__.py
- ModuleB:
  - __init__.py
  - auxiliary.py
```

Using logger should be pretty straightforward. As indicated in the official docs and also on some other answers in this site. But is not working as expected.

On `__main__.py` I have

```
import logging
import logging.config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Initialize logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(fname='FILE.ini')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
    logger.info('The APP has started')
    logger.debug('This goes to the logfile')
```

in `__init__.py` I have

```
#Imports from all the modules
#[...]
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("Package loaded")
```

and in `auxiliary.py` I have

```
import logging

class Auxiliar:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def work(self):
        self.logger.info("From inside AUTH")
```

But this is not working as expected, I get all the messages from `__main__.py` but none from `__init__.py` or auxiliary.py. I have tried also getting a logger only from auxiliary and not `__init__`, same result. The only way its if I leave getLogger() empty to get the root logger on both, but that is not ideal as the name of the module would always be "root" regardless of from where the event is being logged.

I cannot understand what I am missing here.

Comment: What's inside the file `FILE.ini` ? Other than this is not a good practice to put the logger inside the Class scope of Auxiliar

Comment: Please @Glauco, provide the correction / good practice alternative instead of just pointing out that is not correct.

Comment: Here a good starting point https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: After reviewing the link provided I've managed to have inheritance by explicitly declaring the logger names as in the example (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules). However I still don't understand why its failing when using __name__ as the logger. Which was the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround explicit logger name declarations can be used, the correct configuration should be as follows:

On `__main__.py`:

```
import logging
import logging.config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Initialize logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(fname='FILE.ini')
    logger = logging.getLogger('application')  
    logger.info('The APP has started')
    logger.debug('This goes to the logfile')
```

in `__init__.py` nothing is required.

in `auxiliary.py`:

```
import logging
module_logger = logging.getLogger('application.auxiliary')
class Auxiliar:
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('application.auxiliary.Auxiliar') 
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def work(self):
        self.logger.info("From inside Auxiliar clase")
```

This way logs will show correct module hierarchy, but the programmer must control the correct naming convention.